# Metal firepit installation

Tags: soil, landscaping, gravel

I want to put limestone blocks 2x2x5’ for seats in a 10x10, 4’ deep fireplace area, I rented a digger and dig the hole I and plan to put 6” of base inside the entire area first then the blocks around the pit sitting on top of the base, will it sink over time?

I need it to drain and stay put right?

Maybe 4” compacted smaller gravel, then some base? I’m in north Texas incase code is a factor, I figured it would be like a retaining wall or so but can’t seem to find a DIY

Comment: it all depends, soil type, how well you compact the base, the amount of rain or water flowing in or under the base.  Tell us more...and how about a picture of the site?